# Select ONE random row from Table1 where id does not exist in Table2

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to select one (1) **random** row from Table1 where the Data_ID from Table1 does not exist in Table2.

I'm building a site there you can vote on posts (images) and for this page you should only see posts that does not have any votes on it.

Here is a simple structure of my two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Table1` (
  `Id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Data_ID` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Id` (`Id`,`Data_ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Data_ID` (`Data_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4389 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Table2` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Data_ID` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `IP` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Vote_ID` int(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2314 ;
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here is my try but I don't really get random posts.

```
SELECT newTable.*
FROM (    
      SELECT Table1.Id, Table1.Data_ID FROM Table1
      LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2
      ON Table1.Data_ID = Table2.Data_ID
      WHERE Table2.Data_ID IS null
     ) as newTable
WHERE newTable.Id >= ROUND( RAND() * (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM Table1)) LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: @djot Added my try :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You complicating things too much: subquery with `EXISTS` will be enough.

```
SELECT
    Table1.Id,
    Table1.Data_ID
FROM
    Table1
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.Data_ID = Table1.Data_ID
    )
ORDER BY
    RAND()
LIMIT
    1;
```

Here is a `DESCRIBE` results:

```
******************** 1. row *********************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: Table1
         type: index
possible_keys: 
          key: Data_ID
      key_len: 32
          ref: 
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
******************** 2. row *********************
           id: 2
  select_type: DEPENDENT SUBQUERY
        table: Table2
         type: ALL
possible_keys: 
          key:
      key_len: 
          ref: 
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where
```

---

**UPDv1:** There is another fast way, if you like `JOIN` fashion:

```
SELECT
    Table1.Id,
    Table1.Data_ID
FROM
    Table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 USING(Data_ID)
WHERE
    Table2.Id IS NULL
ORDER BY
    RAND()
LIMIT
    1;
```

`DESCRIBE` result:

```
******************** 1. row *********************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: Table1
         type: index
possible_keys: 
          key: Data_ID
      key_len: 32
          ref: 
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
******************** 2. row *********************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: Table2
         type: ALL
possible_keys: 
          key: 
      key_len: 
          ref: 
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where; Not exists; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
```

Comment: Thanks from this i'm getting random posts every time like i want to :)
But it takes about 2.8 sec to get a result.
I don't really understand what you mean with "DESCRIBE results".
Is there something I can change so it will go faster?

Tanks!

Comment: See my edit. (Didn't know {ENTER} in this comment field would post my response)

Comment: Write [`DESCRIBE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) before query instruction to see how MySQL execute it. It will help you analyze slow complex queries.

Comment: @TobiasLindberg See UPDv1 section. Fast enough too

Comment: I added a index and tried using your second answer and i got it down the query to 0.0350 sec! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Get Table1 rows which are not in Table2 and order random number and get the first record.

Using inner query

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1 
WHERE t1.Data_ID NOT IN ( SELECT t2.Data_ID FROM Table2 t2)
ORDER BY FLOOR(RAND()*MAX(Id)) 
LIMIT 1
```

OR using not exists

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT t2.Data_ID FROM Table2 t2 WHERE t2.Data_ID = t1.Data_ID)
ORDER BY FLOOR(RAND()*MAX(t1.Id)) 
LIMIT 1
```

OR Using left join

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Data_ID = t2.Data_ID
WHERE t2.ID IS NULL
ORDER BY FLOOR(RAND()*MAX(t1.Id)) 
LIMIT 1
```

If your table doesn't have a lot of data, you may replace `FLOOR(RAND()*MAX(Id))` with just `RAND()` to get random data. In fact, using `RAND()` always is fine too.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON (t1.id=t2.id AND t1.data_id<>t2data_id) 
WHERE id=(SELECT id FROM table1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1)
```